# Scaling a map so that when printed, 1cm measured is 25000cm real life

Tags: linear-algebra

and I apologize if this is the wrong SE for this question.

I am attempting to scale a map so that $1cm$ measured is $25,000cm$, real life ($1:25000$ scale). The maps original scale is unknown, and the projection is world-mercator.

My map distance width is $6800m$ real life, or $680000cm$.

$680000cm / 25000$ gives me $27.2cm$.

I then take that $27.2cm$ and multiply is by the printers dots-per-cm ($96 dpi / 2.54 cm/in = 37.79 dots-per-cm$) to get how many pixels wide the image will be for the printer, so $27.2cm * 37.79cm$, $1027.8$ (rounded up to $1028$ to avoid subpixels).

I print this out, and measure the entire map. It comes out to $27.2cm$, which multiplied by $25,000$ brings me back to $680000cm$. So far this seems good.

BUT, there is a small park in that map that measures $1.05km$ wide in real life, so $105000cm$. On the printed map, this measures out to be $18.8cm$, which is way too big ($18.8cm x 25000 is 470000cm$, which is way far off of $105000cm$.)

So measuring the whole map yields the correct result, but measuring small components in the map gives the incorrect answers. What do I need to do to ensure that the map is at a $1:25000$ scale so that each cm measured on the printed map is $25000cm$ in real life?

Comment: what is the scale and **projection** of the original map?

Comment: The projection is world-mercator, I'm unsure of the original scale.
I can get the width of the map in pixels, which is 862 for a map that measures 6800m IRL .

Comment: OK, mercator is conformal and hence the scale is roughly constant and direction-independent for small enough patches. So if 862px correspond to 6.8km and come out as 27.2cm, then your park can come out as 18.8cm only if it takes up 596px in the original map and is 4.7km, not 1.05km.

Comment: I see. So my logic for scaling is sound, then? I’ll run the lay/Lon corners thru another source, perhaps the information I was given is incorrect and the Park is 4.7km. Either that, or the images I am working with are not mercator like I was told. edit: didn’t mean to hit return.